# Google Cloud Dataproc - job file erroring on sc.textFile() command

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Here is my file that I submit as a PySpark job in Dataproc, thru the UI

```
# Load file data fro Google Cloud Storage to Dataproc cluster, creating an RDD
# Because Spark transforms are 'lazy', we do a 'count()' action to make sure 
#     we successfully loaded the main data file
allFlt = sc.textFile("gs://mybucket/mydatafile")
allFlt.count()
# Remove header from file so we can work w data ony   
header = allFlt.take(1)[0]
dataOnly = allFlt.filter(lambda line: line != header)
```

It starts and then errors out with

```
allFlt = sc.textFile("gs://thomtect/flightinfo")
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Why is this?  Shouldn't a spark context have alraedy been established by Dataproc?  What do I need to add to my code so that it is accepted as Spark commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/submit-job has an example python spark job submission.

The short answer is to add the following to the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

And to expand a bit on why this is required: when Dataproc runs python scripts, it uses spark-submit (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) instead of running the pyspark shell.

Comment: Thanks Angus.  For both the short answer and the link